# Как получить статус платежа через API ключ(qiwi кошелек)?

Tags: python

Всем привет. Делаю вроде правильно, но получаю всё время только один ответ статуса платежа WATING

```
status, response = conn.check_bill(bill_id)
if status == "PAID":
  conn.remove_bill(bill_id)
  print("Счёт закрыт!")
else:
  print("Текущий статус платежа:", status)
```

Оплачиваю с киви кошелька, оплата проходит успешно, но статус не меняется на PAID. Как получить ответ PAID? Что не так? Вывод последней истории платежа не вариант. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Для полного понимания сути вопроса, необходимо в вопросе указать все функции.

Например, check_bill(bill_id) и remove_bill(bill_id) - нет информации какой результат дают данные функции.

При создании бота в telegram нужна была платежная система - обратился к библиотеке pyQiwiP2P (https://pypi.org/project/pyQiwiP2P).
Немного её доработав получил нужный результат.

К чему я это говорю - удобнее использовать уже готовое решение с возможными доработками.

В вашем случае проблема может заключаться в:

1. Вы оплачиваете счет с аккаунта на котором зарегистрирован api ключ.
2. Отправляете неверные данные в запросе к api, соответственно счет может создаваться, но оформляться неправильно.

И таких нюансов может быть огромное кол-во, поэтому рекомендую делать свой выбор в пользу библиотек, попутно изучая функционал.